# python socket to catch incoming traffic catches nothing

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I set up a UDP socket to receive incoming traffic, but nothing seems to be coming in. I connect it to the server and send a bytearray, but neither confirmation nor exception comes back

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
   data = bytearray(512)
   # data = 'my data'.encode()
   sock.settimeout(5)
   # sock.bind(sock_addr)
   sock.connect(remote_rtp_addr)
   sock.send(data)

   print("empty packet sent")

   while True:
                
       try:
                    
           print("checking for packets..")
           packet, address = sock.recv(512)
           print("Receiving stuff:", packet, address)

       except socket.timeout:
           count += 1
           break
```

I'm checking traffic on wireshark, but don't see any packets to the destination address. what am I missing? thanks!

Comment: Your code have wrong indentation for `while True:` and rest of the code. Is it how you have this in your code?

Comment: bad copy-paste from the actual code. Will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing `ffmpeg` package with `apt install ffmpeg` solved it for me